# Parsing JSON with Argo on Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm attempting to parse JSON data with next format:

`["1", "string", "", "0.16"]`

And these "weird" json should map in next way to my object:

```
myObject.id = json[0] //"1"
myObject.name = json[1] //"string"
myObject.surname = json[2] // ""
myObject.length = json[3] // "0.16"
```

I'm using Argo for parsing, there is example of my code

```
public struct SomeObject {
     public var id: String
     public var name: String
     public var surname: String
     public var length: Float
}

extension SomeObject: Decodable {
    static func create(id: String)(name: String)(surname: String)(length: String) -> SomeObject {
         return SomeObject(id: id, name: name, surname: surname, length: length)
}

    public static func decode(json: JSON) -> Decoded<SomeObject> {
         return SomeObject.create <- actually don't know what to put here, i tried json[0], and decode(json[0]) and casting but still no luck
}
```

What is the correct way to parse that kind of JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

For your information:

```
 let ar = ["1", "string", "", "0.16"]

public struct SomeObject {
    public var id: String?
    public var name: String?
    public var surname: String?
    public var length: Float?
}

extension SomeObject {
    static func create(id: String?, name: String?, surname: String?, length: Float?) -> SomeObject {
        return SomeObject(id: id, name: name, surname: surname, length: length)
    }

    public static func decode(json: AnyObject?) -> SomeObject {
        let js = json as! Array<AnyObject>
        return SomeObject.create(js[0] as? String, name: js[1] as? String, surname: js[2] as? String, length: js[3] as? Float)
    }
}

let someObject = SomeObject.decode(ar)
```

Comment: thanks, but i'm trying to use Argo, so i can integrate it with other entities that i parse with sale lib

Comment: Argo is a web framework right? So only if you can get the data like ```ar``` in the answer is enough. If not not clear about your question then.

Comment: Argo is functional JSON parsing library for Swift, you can find more here https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo

Answer (score 0):

Argo isn't setup to pull out certain indices from arrays like this. What you'll have to do is first decode it to a `[String]` then pick out the indices you want.

```
let values: Decoded<[String]> = decodeArray(json)
return SomeObject.create
  <^> ({ $0[0] } <^> values)
  <*> ({ $0[1] } <^> values)
  <*> ({ $0[2] } <^> values)
  <*> (values >>- { .fromOptional(Float($0[3])) })
```

You can see that I use closures to pull out the required index. The last one also casts the `String` to a `Float` to match your types.

Besides this parsing code, you could also improve the model by using `let` instead of `var` to make it immutable as well as use the Curry framework (https://github.com/thoughtbot/Curry) instead of creating your own curried initializer.